# remove duplicates from collection

Tags: collections, groovy

I want to get a list of all Locales that have a different language, where the ISO3 code is used to identify the language of a Locale. I thought the following should work

```
class ISO3LangComparator implements Comparator<Locale> {

    int compare(Locale locale1, Locale locale2) {
        locale1.ISO3Language <=> locale2.ISO3Language
    }
}

def allLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales().toList()
def uniqueLocales = allLocales.unique {new ISO3LangComparator()}

// Test how many locales there are with iso3 code 'ara'
def arabicLocaleCount = uniqueLocales.findAll {it.ISO3Language == 'ara'}.size()

// This assertion fails
assert arabicLocaleCount <= 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax: you are using [Collection.unique(Closure closure)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

```
allLocales.unique {new ISO3LangComparator()}
```

You should use [Collection.unique(Comparator comparator)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28java.util.Comparator%29)

```
allLocales.unique (new ISO3LangComparator())
```

So simply use `()` instead of `{}`, and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 5):

what Adam said.
or...

```
allLocales.unique{it.ISO3Language}
```

and you forget about the comparator